# Get an effect like google currents for a gridview

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gridview

I've got an app with a list of items displayed in a gridview. I'd love to be able to create an animation effect like used in google current where as a new item comes onto the screen it slowly moves up into a place where it settles.

Currently I've been playing with  android:layoutAnimation on the GridView element, but this doesn't seem to give the kind of control I'm wanting. Does anyone have any pointers on this as to what might need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same Animation. Basically I created a custom Layout which extends LinearLayout and implements onGlobalLayoutListener. In onGlobalLayout() I loop through all childs and use .startAnimation on each child. For the Animation use something like this:

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromDegrees="25"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

</set>
```

**Edit:**
More Info on this here: http://shardulprabhu.blogspot.de/2012/09/google-now-cards-layout.html

Comment: Thanks, is the linear layout you are extending the one that is repeated in the listview/gridview?

Comment: Also, any chance of supplying some of the onGlobalLayoutListener code as I'm not really familiar with doing that?

Comment: Added a link to my original answer. This should help ;)